# VBA Replace number issue

Tags: vba, excel

I have an issue where I need to replace a number with a Loan identifier, the problem I am having is the Loan identifier contains the number that needs replacing so I am ending up with something like "LOAN1592LOAN3161LOAN29269704932LOAN2926970411" when what I actually want is if the loan number is 6 for it to be replaced with LOAN31617932 not the above. Any thoughts how I can stop this from happening? I hope this makes sense. Please see the segment of my code as follows:

```
    Columns("e:e").Select
    Selection.Replace What:="5", Replacement:="LOAN15926711", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False

     Columns("e:e").Select
    Selection.Replace What:="6", Replacement:="LOAN31617932", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False

     Columns("e:e").Select
    Selection.Replace What:="7", Replacement:="LOAN29269704", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False

     Columns("e:e").Select
    Selection.Replace What:="8", Replacement:="LOAN57538987", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
```

Comment: Sample layout of data would help.

Comment: column e depending on which file the macro is run on will have a number from 1-8 in it. The number will always be the same in said file.

Comment: I would think a loop through column e and evaluate each cell for the number and either an if statement or select case would do the job. `Replace` will look at the entire column and any instance of the number you are looking for will be changed, instead of the full cell value being the number.

Comment: You'll want `If` statements I think.  The reason it's doing that, is when you replace the cell that has `5` with `LOAN15926711`, the very next replace will take the `6` in that string, and add in "LOAN...". Just do an If statement, similar to `For each cell in Columns("E:E")` // If cell.Value = 5 Then ...`

Comment: `The number will always be the same in said file` so the entire column is 5?

Comment: @findwindow yes the entire column would be 5,6,7 or 8

Comment: So 4 possible numbers in the column. Then yea, Batman's answer should work. Or you could easily do an `if` statement in the next column...

Comment: Sorry if I am being stupid here but would an if statement not replace the number as did my what and replace statement above?

Comment: If statement then copy/paste over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `xlWhole`:

```
Sub luxation()
Columns("e:e").Replace What:="5", Replacement:="LOAN15926711", LookAt:=xlWhole, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
End Sub
```

Before:

[image]

and after:

[image]

Note:

The **55** and **555** are ignored!

Comment: D'oh! Nice call with `xlWhole`, I totally forgot that and went for a more complicated route :P

Comment: @BruceWayne  I have stumbled over this more than once in the past.

Comment: @JDRows - You can mark his answer as "the answer", by clicking the check mark left of his post.

Answer (score 2):

I'd do `If` (or `Select Case`) instead.  See my comment above as to why. Does this work:

```
Sub t()
Dim cel As Range, rng As Range
Dim lastRow&

lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).row

Set rng = Range("E1:E" & lastRow)
For Each cel In rng
    If InStr(1, cel.Value, "2") Then cel.Value = "LOAN15926711"
    If InStr(1, cel.Value, "6") Then cel.Value = "LOAN31617932"
    ' etc. etc.
Next cel
End Sub
```

If the cell will *only* have `5`, `6`, etc. then just do

`If cel.Value = "6" Then ...`

Edit2: But I'd listen to @GarysStudent, adding the simple `xlWhole` is what you want. Simple, clean, and easy.

Comment: Two problems. OP is searching for a digit within string not entire cell. And what if 2 digits occur in same string? Edit: uh, maybe I misunderstood OP.

Comment: @findwindow - Yeah, caught that and updated. Not sure about the 2 digits, will need OP to opine.

Comment: No, I think you had it right, I had it wrong. Column only contains one single number.